# Sliding overlay with scrolling text

Tags: html, css

I am completely new here and experimenting with an overlay sliding up with text over an image. The overlay is off and I'm having some trouble fixing it. This is for a responsive gallery where all the images do the same thing.

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Flexbox Image Gallery</h1>
      <div class="img-area">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="single-img"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sem et tortor consequat id porta nibh. Ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis. Pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Nam at lectus urna duis convallis. Massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula. Et malesuada fames ac turpis. Eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit. Ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu. Volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit. Aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat. Ornare lectus sit amet est placerat in egestas erat. Adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium. Quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the css for it.

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
}
.wrapper h1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
}

.img-area{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.single-img{
  padding: 0 20px 20px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 40%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: left;
  width: 70%;

}
```

The goal is for the text to be at the top of the overlay and you can scroll down. The image dimensions are 500x500. The text should still have a little space from the edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size mismatch is because of the padding on the `single-img` div is counted as part of its width.  You could remove the padding from that div and put it on the parent to avoid that.  I made an example [here](https://codepen.io/extrachrisb/pen/QWLaepo) with a few changes.